Best practice for overriding a library function?
I have the following situation.
I have a root project which contains a subproject.
This subproject is intended as a library, which you can either build stand-alone or it can be build alongside another project.
In the library I have to allocate memory at several locations.
I wish however, to be able to override this functionality.
For example, in the library I have a call to malloc(ptr).
And I wish to be able to replace these calls by a library consumer (in this case the rootproject).
The rootproject in this case should override/replace the calls in the library without the library being dependent on the rootproject.
For extra context I'm using this MACRO way because it is more performant than using function pointers for example, I am interested in high performance allocations in this case.
My question boils down to this:
What is the best practice for extending libraries like this?
I've found several related questions, but I am specifically interested in the best practice for these things; that it's possible I am already aware of.
What I've so far to achieve what I want is the following.

I've defined a header with macro's replacing the allocations like so: HDR_MALLOC(ptr) malloc(ptr).
Every malloc(ptr) in the library now uses HDR_MALLOC(ptr) instead.
When the library is built standalone it simply uses this definition.
In the rootproject I've also defined a header with the macro HDR_MALLOC(ptr) 

Now when building the library this works correctly, the rootproject correctly "overrides" the library's HDR_MALLOC.
When rootproject uses the library, the library calls the rootproject's implementation instead of it's own.

your way is probably the fastest. another approach would be to make your own library which implements/wraps malloc (change the exported symbol name) and put that earlier in the linking order. might need to add flags to ignore multiple definition.

In my experience, most libraries seem to reach for a macro-based system of configuration, with the ability for consumers to override by defining said macro themselves. The code pattern tends to be:
#if defined(LIB_CONFIG_HEADER)
  #include LIB_CONFIG_HEADER
#else
  // Include some reasonable defaults
  #include <stdlib.h>
  ...
#endif
 
#if !defined(LIB_ALLOC)
  #define LIB_ALLOC(_size) calloc(1u, _size)
#endif

This has the bonus flexibility of allowing otherwise invalid expressions like
#define LIB_ALLOC(_size) ...
#define LIB_ALLOC_T(_type) ((_type) *)LIB_ALLOC(sizeof(_type))

Since these are handled by the preprocessor, it also tends to be a useful pattern for embedded systems where a full or compliant standard library is not available.
Systems which require a more complex set of injectable behaviours tend to lean towards the function-pointer / vtable approach, which often also includes allocation methods. While this approach does involve some amount of indirection, in practice it is not a large amount of overhead.
There is also a third option involving weak linkage, but I would not recommend this.

Use function pointers, eg.
// lib.h
void libfoo(int one, double two, struct bar *three, void *(*alocfx)(size_t));

and, in the main project, call the library function
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lib.h"
int main(void) {
    libfoo(1, 3.14159, NULL, malloc);
}


You can implement the library function such that if the function pointer is NULL it uses standard library's malloc(). Of course add this behaviour to the library documentation :)

Thanks for elaborating.
What I meant is that inside library (not exposed to the main project) the function is called (in this case malloc).
The library consumer simply calls exposed functions which will internally call the function to override.
Right now I simply replace the MACRO as defined in the library by the MACRO as defined in the rootproject.
This way I "replace" all calls to malloc when the library is compiled against the project.
I was just wondering if there was a better, best-practice way which will also remain performant.

The MACRO replacement inside the library only happens if you compile it again and again and again. If you compile your library once (and link with gcc ... -lfoo) no macro changes in the main project will change the behaviour of the library.

I'd say the function pointer is better practice since, OK, you recompile the library with project X, but what about runtime when library search may depend on the PATHs, what about when you have several sub libraries or subparts using foo.dll : one macro "redefinition" may apply (depending on how you load it, but it's a lib so it should work however). Seems to me that with fn pointers, this risk avoided, so "better practice"
